# Implementing (extending) Path

Tags: java, extends, implements

I'm trying to create an object that would be able to deal with the file managment in my program.

Path interface has almost all methods I need, but I would like to add some custom ones. If I implement Path in my object, I'll have to override all the path's methods.

Is there a way to create an object that has all the methods of the Path interface and some additional methods, without actually overriding the methods of an interface?

In a way, I'd like to extend Path interface, but be able to define any additional methods bodies too.

Comment: What would you gain from extending `Path`?  I've seen more extension of `SimpleFileVisitor` instead.

Comment: You are going to have to explain why you want to extend Path.  There is probably a way to accomplish your objective without doing that.

Answer (score 1):

I might warn you about some little points about the Path Interface. Also, I would have two suggestions for implementing this interface.

To my knowledge, Path Interface is there to create a type reference point for the paths in file operator objects. A Path can be created with Paths Helper Class (pay attention to -s). But, it is never implemented by any class. Thus, it is an interface that is used for passing data within a common type. This means that, coder is supposed to send information using Path Interface as the type, then use the Path Typed Object on other class operation that is declared as receiving Path Type Object. As a result, ,in my opinion, implementing path class is not really a necessity.

As I mentioned, I can suggest you two things: Though, these type of practices are not good design decisions. This issue is also mentioned in JavaSE7 Doc: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toAbsolutePath%28%29)

1) First, you don't have to add behavior to all methods in the interface. You can declare them with a "not implemented" msg log and return nulls.

2) But a better way is to use an abstract class as Ali Alamiri mentioned. I personally would not go into the fuss to create a subclass for the abstract and just implement the methods that I want. If I want to make more fault tolerant app of it, then use the subclass to carry all unimplemented methods and use a warning msg log for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Remember for example [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)? It's a very similar thing to your case - it is a thin wrapper (a decorator) around any [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) which makes it buffered and has some additional methods (can read lines).

```
public class DecoratedPath implements Path {
    private final Path path;

    public DecoratedPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public DecoratedPath(String stringPath) {
        this(Paths.get(stringPath));
    }

    // add any additional constructors / factory methods you like

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Path other) {
        return path.compareTo(other);
    }

    @Override
    public int endsWith(Path other) {
        return path.endsWith(other);
    }

    // Etc. for all the methods of the Path interface.
    // They'll all delegate to the methods of the path field.
    // You can also enhance some of them, if you want to,
    // to return DecoratedPath instead of Path.

    // your additional methods
}
```

Usage:

```
DecoratedPath path = new DecoratedPath("/some/path");
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that you should specify what is the behaviour you are missing. There is probably a way to achieve it without having to decorate the `Path` interface. Have you looked at the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class? Or the various IO libraries out there?

Comment: P.S. To overcome the hassle of many methods that do nothing but delegate, you can take a look at Lombok. It's awesome. http://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an `abstract` class that implements the `Path` interface. In this class you can implement methods or leave them unimplemented so that another class can deal with them. Then you can extend this abstract class and override any method you want, and you don't have to override every single method.

for example:

```
public abstract class AbstractPath implements Path
{
    //All methods declarations from Path interface
}

public class Base extends AbstractPath
{
   //Override any method declared in AbstractPath
}
```

Comment: That just pushes the problem up to `AbstractPath`. The OP has to either implement all Path methods or delegate them to a private member `Path` instance.

Comment: @JimGarrison what I understood from the OP explanation is that this is what he wants, to be able to implement some methods of the interface and add his own methods. So no reason to downvote the answer if the OP hasn't said if it was what he wanted or not.